# Python : Difference between static methods vs class method

Tags: python, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between @staticmethod and @classmethod in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)

- I am learning OOP in python and came to know about these two methods
- It seems that the difference in terms of syntax is that class methods are implicitly passed the class they belong to as their first parameter

> ```
> class Circle:
>   all_circles = [] # class variable
>
>   @staticmethod
>   def total_area():
>       for c in Circle.all_circles: # hardcode class name
>           # do somethig
>
>   @classmethod
>   def total_area(cls):
>       for c in cls.all_circles: # no hardcode class name
>           # do something
> ```

I see class method as more flexible since we don't hardcode the class

Question:
- Is it even a question which one is better? @staticmethod or @classmethod?
- what are the scenarios suitable to use of each one of these methods?

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python

Comment: The question I'd ask is not which one is better, but which one is appropriate-- for the particular situation you are in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A classmethod gets passed the class 'cls' that it was called upon. For more details see: [What is the difference between @staticmethod and @classmethod in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)