# Refer to own class in a static method

Tags: python

Is there a shorthand for referring to its own class in a static method?

Say I have this piece of code:

```
class SuperLongClassName(object):

    @staticmethod
    def sayHi():
        print 'Hi'

    @staticmethod
    def speak():
        SuperLongClassName.sayHi()  # Is there a shorthand?
```

Comment: you should use a class method instead of a static method

[more info here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744223/python-difference-between-static-methods-vs-class-method

Answer (score 10):

Yes, use `@classmethod` instead of `@staticmethod`. The whole point of `@staticmethod` is to remove the extra class parameter if you don't need it.

```
class SuperLongClassName(object):

    @classmethod
    def sayHi(cls):
        print 'Hi'

    @classmethod
    def speak(cls):
        cls.sayHi()
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably want a [`classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod). It works like a `staticmethod`, but takes the class as an implicit first argument.

```
class Claaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaass(object):
    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
         print cls.__name__

Claaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaass.foo() # prints Claaa...
```

Warning:

```
class Subclaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaass(
        Claaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaass):
    pass

Subclaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaass.foo() # prints Subclaaa...
```

Alternatively, define a shorter alias for your class at module level:

```
class Claaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaass2(object):
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        return _cls2
_cls2 = Claaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaass2

# prints True
print (Claaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaass2 is
       Claaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaass2.foo())
```